# Difference between `AsyncIterable[T]` and `Iterable[Awaitable[T]]`?

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, generator, python-asyncio

Take these two following functions:

```
import asyncio

def a():
    for index in range(2):
        # Capture `index` as `local_index` in case awaiting is postponed.
        async def next_index(local_index=index):
            # Simulate network request.
            await asyncio.sleep(0)

            return local_index

        yield next_index()

async def b():
    for index in range(2):
        # Simulate network request.
        await asyncio.sleep(0)

        yield index
```

`a` returns an `Iterable[Awaitable[int]]`. `b` returns an `AsyncIterable[int]`. Iteration for both can be done like so:

```
async def main():
    for index in a():
        print(await index)

    async for index in b():
        print(index)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Output:

```
0
1
0
1
```

The key thing from the above example is that I was able to yield `Awaitable`s without an outer `async` because the inner function is `async`.

1. Is there anything an `AsyncIterable[T]` allows over an `Iterable[Awaitable[T]]` in terms of functionality?

I also have a very related question. From [PEP 492 - Asynchronous Iterators and "async for"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#asynchronous-iterators-and-async-for):

> An asynchronous iterator object must implement an **anext** method
> (or, if defined with CPython C API, tp_as_async.am_anext slot)
> returning an awaitable.

2. Because an outer `async` was not required to yield `Awaitable`s, does `__anext__` offer exclusive functionality over a synchronous `__next__` returning `Awaitable`s?

This is where I'm probably missing something, but from my current understanding, the asynchronous protocol and `StopAsyncIteration` look like they can be mimicked using the synchronous protocol and `StopIteration` (with less brevity of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One big issue you're missing is how the end of the loop is handled.

An asynchronous iterator's `__anext__` returns an awaitable, which can suspend, raise `StopIteration` with a value to produce the next element, or raise `StopAsyncIteration` to signal the end of the loop. (The PEP says "To stop iteration `__anext__` must raise a StopAsyncIteration exception.", but the StopAsyncIteration exception really happens when the awaitable is awaited, not synchronously when `__anext__` is called.)

In contrast, if you try to make a regular iterable with awaitable elements, then the iterator's `__next__` needs to raise `StopIteration` to end the loop.

This means that `__next__` can't return until it *knows* whether or not there will be another element. `__next__` is synchronous, so while it's figuring this out, control cannot return to the event loop. This means you might waste a bunch of time synchronously waiting for network traffic or something while all other work stalls.

You can work around this with even more manual handling, but it gets really awkward on both ends, especially the iterator's end, and you need some sort of equivalent of StopAsyncIteration to disambiguate "here's the next element" from "loop's done".